# no existence of limit for a function

Tags: real-analysis

Please, I want to prove that this function $$ g(t)=\begin{cases} 1, &x\neq 0,\\ 0, &x=0,\end{cases}$$ has no limit at $0$

is it correct if I take  two sequences $x_n=0$ and $y_n= \frac{1}{n}$

the two goes to $0$, but $g(x_n)=0$ and $g(y_n)=1 $

so limit of $g(x)$ when $x$ goes to $0$ do not exist?

Comment: Another thing to mention is that this function has removable discontinuity, since:

$L^+ = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+}g(x)$

$L^- = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-}g(x)$:

$L^+=L^- = 1$.

Yet, 

$L^+, L^- \neq g(0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

This function has  a limit at $0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g (x)=1$. The value of $g$ at $0$ is not involved in the definition of limit.

Ref. See the section 'The Limit of a Function' in Baby Rudin.

Comment: and my example why is false?  please

Comment: @NoraNour It is false because you are not allowed to take $x_n=0$ when you are finding the limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $0$ belongs to every neighborhood of $0$. Hence, the value of $g$ at $0$ is (implicitely) involved.

Comment: My bad... It's been so long since I had to use the definition of limits...